# Pandas - merge multiple time columns and fill values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`):

```
index    time    val1    time2    val2
0        0.2     1       0.1      2
1        0.3     3       0.4      2
2        0.4     1       0.8      9
3                        1.0      2
```

I need to merge the `time` columns, sort them, then fill the missing values in a "downwards" manner.
The expected output is like so:

```
index    time    val1    val2
0        0.1     -       2
1        0.2     1       2
2        0.3     3       2
3        0.4     1       2
4        0.8     1       9
5        1.0     1       2
```

Comment: Is `0.1     -       2` first row correct? Not necessary `1.0 NaN     2` ?

Comment: NaN would be preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with some preprocessing - `rename` time column and convert index to column, then sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), remove dupes by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns={'time':'time1'}).reset_index(),
                      'time', i='index', j='t')
        .sort_values(['time','val2'])
        .drop_duplicates('time')
        .dropna(subset=['time'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
   val1  val2  time
0   1.0     2   0.1
1   1.0     2   0.2
2   3.0     2   0.3
3   3.0     2   0.4
4   1.0     9   0.8
5   NaN     2   1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

create 2 dataframes from the main dataframe df like this:
**I'm assuming index is not a column**

```
df1= df.iloc[:,[0,1,3]]
df2= df.iloc[:,[2,1,3]]
df2=df2.rename(columns={'time2':'time'})
```

then merge both the data frames

```
df3=pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

sort as per the time value.

```
df4=df3.sort_values("time").drop_duplicates('time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Solution is not completed.

Comment: @jezrael I forgot to sort earlier which i've done now. Is it complete now?

Comment: please add your output to answer.

Comment: @jezrael in your output answer for t=0.4 the val values are:val1=3 and val2=2 whereas he expects val1=1 and val2= 2 for t=0.4

Comment: yop, and it was reason for comment under question